# How to add Dependencies in project level Gradle in latest version?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Project level Gradle is updated, now it looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

anyway, I need to add this to my project level Gradle :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

  }
```

I did read [this article](https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration) and still can't understand how to implement this!

Comment: id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false

Comment: I am unable to add new dependencies in Module. Can you please tell me how you have added. You can answer my new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add dependencies as follows in your project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Before adding
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}
```

So to add new dependencies with the new version, you can add it directly as follow:

```
//with classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' to be added
//after adding
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false.
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false
}
```